# Как подключить библиотеку распознавание речи Vosk в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, kaldi

В Unity требуется перевод голоса в текст, чтоб работало под Android, Windows, IOs.

Что я сделал:

1. В Linux'e собрал Kaldi как показано в [инструкции](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install#compilation-from-source);
2. В Linux'e cобрал библиотеку "libkaldiwrap.so" как указано в [инструкции](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install#c-build);
3. Получившиеся папки "gen","model" и библиотеку "libkaldiwrap.so" положил в Unity проект (под Windows) в папку "Assets\Plugins\Vosk".

В результате Unity выдаёт ошибку:

DllNotFoundException: kaldiwrap
Kaldi.VoskPINVOKE+SWIGStringHelper..cctor () (at Assets/Plugins/Vosk/gen/VoskPINVOKE.cs:28)

Скажите пожалуйста, что я сделал неправильно и как могу это исправить. Спасибо.

[image: Код из файла VoskPINVOKE.cs]

Comment: вы скомпилировали исполняемый файл (в частности, библиотеку) для одной операционной системы, и пытаетесь выполнить его на другой операционной системе. естественно, он не будет выполняться.

Comment: [Вот что нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61381745/12888024)